# How to manipulate this array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am a beginner in PHP. I am trying to make an operation in this array. I want to insert this array in my database like on to many in a table.But before the insertion i have to modify the array values.

this is my array.

```
$services=[0=>('id_e'=>91701,'id_s'=03),
           1=>('id_e'=>'','id_s'=>01),
           2=>('id_e'=>'','id_s'=>02)
           ];
```

It has to become like as follow.

```
$services=[0=>('id_e'=>91701,'id_s'=>03),
           1=>('id_e'=>'91701','id_s'=>01),
           2=>('id_e'=>'91701','id_s'=>02)
           ];
```

And then i want insert into the database. Any idea please?

Comment: So, if `id_e` is empty, set it to previous non-empty `id_e`?

Comment: Thank you very much it's very clear demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$id_e = null;
foreach ($services as &$row) {
    if ($row['id_e']) $id_e = $row['id_e'];
    else $row['id_e'] = $id_e;
}
unset($row);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/232044)</kbd>

Comment: @Devarajan: as already requested, it is usual here to click the tick mark adjacent to questions if something helped you. It removes a question out of unanswered lists and thanks the person who helped you. I will downvote your question, and will undownvote upon request once you have done this.